# texture paint not showing up on object

Tags: texture-painting

Im sorry if this is a redundant question but Ive searched for a while, and have followed many tutorials. I follow all the steps but when I paint nothing shows up. . [image: here is a screenshot]

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: In edit mode check the direction of your normals - sometimes things get inverted and then the paint is on the inside.